# Content page not subject to page css

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that add through jquery some content to the current visited web page.
The problem is that the elements I create are subject to current web page css rules, for example if web page css say all div have some properties then my div elements get this property.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Manually reset all relevant properties to their default/desired values, perhaps including `!important` to make sure that the styles cannot be overridden. Or use an iframe, using the `seamless` attribute for a smooth integration.

Comment: Can't you assign your own divs classnames and use CSS rules for them?